# File comparison and summaries in Java

Tags: java

I am new in java and written code to compare 2 files which contains 3-5 pages. If there is any difference in any file for any line, then it produces the location/line where the difference found.

However my code is comparing only 1 line and not all the lines and pages.

When I execute the code I'm getting output in an unreadable format:

> Two files have different content. They differ at line 6
>   File1 has ð¼Ñêz£¿§Å‰…,  ¡   ‰/û|f\ZþçŠæ?6ï!Y´_áoœ]Aó

The code:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class CompareTextFiles
 {   
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{  
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("v1.docx"));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("v2.docx"));      
String line1 = reader1.readLine();
String line2 = reader2.readLine();
boolean areEqual = true;
int lineNum = 1;
while (line1 != null || line2 != null)
{
    if(line1 == null || line2 == null)
    {
        areEqual = false;
        break;
    }
    else if(! line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2))
    {
        areEqual = false;
        break;
    }
    line1 = reader1.readLine();
    line2 = reader2.readLine(); 
    lineNum++;
 }
 if(areEqual)
 {
    System.out.println("Two files have same content.");
 }
 else
 {
    System.out.println("Two files have different content. They differ at line "+lineNum);   
    System.out.println("File1 has "+line1+" and File2 has "+line2+" at line "+lineNum);
}
reader1.close();
reader2.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Why not read each file in and save them to two different `List` -> `list.add(line)`?

Comment: For fixing your character problem u can use InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("filePath", *add_charset_here*));

Comment: why are you using break, this takes you out of the while loop

Comment: The characters a nonsensical because you are comparing binary files. Try with .txt files.

Comment: using a do/while will simplify the method

Comment: The answer is spot on: there is no point in **line by line** comparisons of **binary** data. You either should only read/compare **bytes**, or you should use a **library** that is able to turn the binary content into "text" ... if you are interested in comparing content. In that sense, the real question is more: what do you *actually* try to do here?

Answer (score 1):

> When i am executing code gettitng outout in unreadalbe format

You are reading from a `.docx` file. It's like this:

Try opening your `v1.docx` file with a `notepad.exe` or `wordpad.exe`, and look what weird characters you will see.

You should find a library which support reading `.docx` file types.